# Currying in Scala like JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scala, functional-programming, currying

Im new to functional programming in Scala and i'd like to know how to achieve the concept of currying in Scala. Below i have given an example of currying in JavaScript and I'd like to know the Scala equivalent of the same code.

```
var add = function(x){
 return function(y){
  return x + y;
 };
};

console.log(add(1)(2));

var increment = add(1);
var addTen = add(10);

increment(2); //3

addTen(2); //12
```

Any Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first rewrite your example in more modern ECMAScript:

```
const add = x => y => x + y;
```

The Scala equivalent is very similar, it looks *almost* like this, the only difference is the `val` instead of `const` (although we could actually use `var` in both cases, and make the code truly identical):

```
// almost correct, but doesn't compile
val add = x => y => x + y
```

Except that doesn't work because Scala doesn't know what the types are, so we have to help just a little bit by either declaring the types of `x` and `y`, so Scala can properly infer the type of `add` *or* declare the type of `add`, so Scala can properly infer the types of the functions:

```
val add                    = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x + y
// or
val add: Int => Int => Int =  x       =>  y       => x + y
```

Scala also allows us to write them with a proper fat arrow if we want to:

```
val add                  = (x: Int) ⇒ (y: Int) ⇒ x + y
// or
val add: Int ⇒ Int ⇒ Int =  x       ⇒  y       ⇒ x + y
```

So, as you can see, apart from the type declarations, the code is actually *identical*.

```
println(add(1)(2)) // 3

val increment = add(1)
val addTen = add(10)

increment(2) //=> 3
addTen(2)    //=> 12
```

There is, however, another kind of currying in Scala, that is actually built into the language. In Scala, methods (which are *different* from functions) can have zero or more parameter lists, unlike most other languages (including ECMAScript) where there is always exactly one (potentially empty) parameter list. Methods that are defined with multiple parameter lists are called "curried" methods:

```
// this is a *method*, not a *function*, and thus different from the OP's example!
def addMeth(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
```

In Scala, we can convert a method into a function using η-expansion; this is written by placing an underscore after the name of the method:

```
// this converts the method `addMeth` into an anonymous function 
// and assigns it to the variable `addFunc`
val addFunc = addMeth _
```

Now we can do the same things we did above using our curried `addFunc` function:

```
println(addFunc(1)(2)) // 3

val increment = addFunc(1)
val addTen = addFunc(10)

increment(2) //=> 3
addTen(2)    //=> 12
```

But we can also use our `addMeth` method directly:

```
println(addMeth(1)(2)) // 3

val increment = addMeth(1) _
val addTen = addMeth(10) _

increment(2) //=> 3
addTen(2)    //=> 12
```

So, unlike ECMAScript, Scala actually has a language built-in concept of currying, but

- not for functions, only for methods and
- not based on individual parameters but on parameter lists

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
def add(x:Int)(y:Int) = x+y

def increment = add(1) _

def addTen = add(10) _

val three = add(1)(2)
val four = increment(3)
```